# Why does MFC DoModal returns -1 ? What does -1 mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, mfc

I am very new to MFC and have been asked to create a MFC application in Visual Studio 2008. I am trying to Create two dialog. The first one opens on launch and if OK is pressed on the first one, the second dialog opens. However my first dialog opens properly but the second one returns -1 when I call DoModal(). Can anybody please let me know what am I doing wrong ? The -1 according to MSDN documentation is "something has gone wrong". I couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
// The main file from where the dialogs are launched - Encrypt.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Encrypt.h"
#include "MainDialog.h"
#include "AddlDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CEncryptApp, CWinApp)
 ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CEncryptApp::CEncryptApp()
{

}

CEncryptApp theApp;

BOOL CEncryptApp::InitInstance()
{
    CWinApp::InitInstance();
    AfxEnableControlContainer();
    AfxInitRichEdit();

    CMainDialog dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();

    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {
        CAddlDlg ldg;
        INT_PTR nResponse = ldg.DoModal();

        switch (nResponse)
        {
            case -1: 
                AfxMessageBox(_T("-1"));
                break;
            case IDABORT:
                AfxMessageBox(_T("1!")); 
                break;
            case IDOK:
                AfxMessageBox(_T("2!")); 
                break;
             case IDCANCEL:
                AfxMessageBox(_T("3!"));  
                break;
             default:
                AfxMessageBox(nResponse);  
             break;
        };


    }
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    {

    }

return FALSE;
}
```

This is the main dialog

```
// Main Dialog

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Encrypt.h"
#include "MainDialog.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
 #define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMainDialog, CDialog)

CMainDialog::CMainDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
     : CDialog(CMainDialog::IDD, pParent)
 {
      m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
  }

 CMainDialog::~CMainDialog()
 {
 }

void CMainDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
 }

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainDialog, CDialog)
   ON_WM_PAINT()
   ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
   //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

  BOOL CMainDialog::OnInitDialog()
  {
     CDialog::OnInitDialog();

   SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);          // Set big icon
   SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);     // Set small icon
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
 }

 void CMainDialog::OnPaint()
 {
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
       int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
   }
   else
   {
       CDialog::OnPaint();
    }
}

 HCURSOR CMainDialog::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
 }
```

// The second dialog

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Encrypt.h"
#include "AddlDlg.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CAddlDlg, CDialog)
CAddlDlg::CAddlDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CAddlDlg::IDD, pParent)
{      // Reaches until here
}

CAddlDlg::~CAddlDlg()
{
}

void CAddlDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
   CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BOOL CAddlDlg::OnInitDialog() 
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    return TRUE;
} 

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAddlDlg, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

When I try printing debug statements, I enter into the constructor of the second dialog but the OnInitDialog never gets called. Can someone please help me?

**UPDATE :: **

The error I see on further debugging says it is on line 311 in dlgcore.cpp in the function ::CreateDialogIndirect with the actual error is

> ::CreateDialogIndirect() did NOT create the window (ie. due to error in template) and returns NULL.

I do not what that means. Can some one explain me ?

Comment: You should use the debugger and step through the call to DoModal.

Comment: Why was this downvoted ? It was a genuine question with all the details.

Comment: I was not the one who down voted.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN site:

> The return value is –1 if the function could not create the dialog box, or IDABORT if some other error occurred, in which case the Output window will contain error information from GetLastError.

Error citation can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5.aspx

The system is unable to create and run your dialog. You can read the provided MSDN link for more information.

It is likely you have a control or DLL that is not registered correctly that the dialog needs and therefore cannot find.

Comment: Yes.  And, my guess would be using a RichEdit 2.0 control since she does have AfxInitRichEdit() already in there.  If that's the case, try using AfxInitRichEdit2().  If she is using OLE controls, then she should also call AfxEnableControlContainer() in InitInstance().

Comment: @StarPilot I debugged this further and noticed the error is at line 311 in dlgcore.cpp. On further reading below it says "::CreateDialogIndirect() did NOT create the window (ie. due to error in template)
   *    and returns NULL."

Comment: @Surya Humor us here.  What I would do is delete all your controls off the dialog and see if the dialog can then be created.  If it still fails, then it is not due to a control on the dialog as we suspect it is.  If it succeeds, then it is due to a control on the dialog.  At that point, add the controls back one at a time (or one type at a time, e.g. STATICs, EDITs, etc) until the error repeats and then you will have found the offending control.

Comment: Simple test: Create the second dialog first.  If it fails, it has nothing to do with the first dialog.  An ActiveX control can be the culprit too.